# Google analytics API with segment

Tags: php, api, analytics, google-analytics-api, segment

I just discovered the segment condition "Date of first visit" in GA.

I would like to pull data with this segment from the API but for some reason when i used the Google segment list(https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list#try-it),
I can't see any segment that has this condition.

Did any of you guy experience this or try to use this type of segment with the API before please?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Date of Session segments now appear in the Google Analytics Management API when you call the [segments.list()](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list) method

Answer (score 0):

if you did not create any segment before, there is no result show in segments.list();

the default segments are built by Combining Conditions, please check the document

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/segments#dimsmets-conditions

the default segment comes from rule base, maybe that can solve your question.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/6PpoY.png