# How to include custom segments in the list of segments when querying the Google Analytics API?

Tags: google-analytics, google-analytics-api

This may be a possible duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783444/google-analytics-api-with-segment), but according to all the Google Analytics documentation I really should be able to pull my list of custom segments.

Since I have a very large list of them, it would be suboptimal for me to manually copy the segment ids over one at a time.

I'm following [this](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtSegmentGuide) walk through. Steps to reproduce:

1. Create a custom segment using date of first session in your Google Analytics account.
2. Authorize the Google Analytics guide to access your Google Analytics account.
3. Try their on-page query tester, and inspect whether your custom segment is there.

One thing I've already ruled out was the user that created the segment. I've manually created a segment with the same user that I'm querying the API with and it still does not show. Is there a flag I need to set somewhere to include custom segments?

Edit:

It turns out that it will list *some* custom segments, but not ones created with date of first session, so this is a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21783444/google-analytics-api-with-segment), which means that there is a bug in the Google Analytics API.

Comment: What does total results say? The default number of results returned is probably 100, have you set the max results up to say 1000? have you tried to use the nextlink to get the rest of the results? Your example walk though doesn't use the next link to get the rest of the results.   I don't think there is a bug in the API I just don't think you are requesting the rest of the data.

Comment: @DaImTo Total result is way less than 100.

Comment: @DalmTo Yeah, I'm using the Python client and when I call the next_chunck() method I get a

`if self.resumable.size() is None:

AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'size'`

Error. Also, when I add other custom segments they show up in a growing list of segments. I really think the error is on Google Analytics side here.

Comment: @DalmTO Further evidence that this is Google's fault: `API error : 400 : Segment [My_Custom_Segment_id] is not supported in the API.` Which means the reason Google is not including it is because they know that queries of this type will fail

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So after days of trying to solve this one I've come to the conclusion that it cannot be done as asked.

There is, however, another way to do it. For every segment set up a daily (or weekly, etc) email report to a email as a TSV. In each email body specify the name of the segment so when you're consuming the emails you can know which segment the attached TSV is for. It doesn't look like the daily reports were designed with segments in mind, since non of the metadata included in the TSV mentions which segment it is for.

From there it's trivial. Connect to the email address using an IMAP client once a day and update the numbers.

Note that the daily email only contains the numbers for that day (not a specified range), so you'll need to first generate the report one time with the historical data to load in.

While hacky, one nice thing about this approach is that it keeps your reports in sync with your (faked through email) api code (provided you match the column headings in the TSV). So, if for example, a new filter is included into a report, the new daily fields will continue to update.

Unfortunately though, the past data won't be reflected in the change.

Obviously this isn't great, but if you are monitoring daily cohorts it's the best you've got if you need to stay with Google Analytics. I have raised this as a bug to the Google Analytics developers, but I haven't heard back as to whether or not they plan to fix it.

Answer (score 2):

There was a [bug](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=467) which is now fixed. So it is now possible to list the Date of Session Segments in the Google Analytics [Management API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/mgmt/v3/mgmtReference/management/segments/list#try-it) by calling the segments.list() method.